# Centralized Axios API Cancel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have a React application and I have a centralized API Class. So All of the API calls I make, go through APIClass. I call a specific function of an API class with props and that fetches the data using APICaller and returns it asynchronously. The problem is that I need to implement axios cancel token for it and not sure how could I achieve it. In the below setup, callAPIone would return the data while callAPItwo would fail. How can I make it so second call would cancel first one?

```
let i = await this.apiClass.callAPIone(1);
let y = await this.apiClass.callAPIone(2,cancel);
```

Then within apiClass, I have functions like

```
callAPIone = async (param,cancel) => {
    return await ApiCaller(param,cancel)
}
```

Then within ApiCaller I have

```
async function ApiCaller(param,apiCancel) {
    let source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    if (apiCancel) source.cancel("Request canceled.");
    let params = param
    return await axios
        .get(apiRoute, { headers, params, cancelToken: source.token })
        .then((response) => OnSuccess(response))
        .catch((e) => OnError(e.message));
}
```

Comment: avoid then and catch with async/await

Comment: any reason why? how can I do error logging properly then?

Comment: `await` unpacks the promise and you can use standard `try..catch`

Comment: `apiCancel` cancels the first set of request. In other hand, `source.cancel("Request canceled.");` should be out the `ApiCaller` function. i.e: a global variable or external instance.

Comment: oh Ic thank you @Daniel so I do `let source = axios.CancelToken.source();` inside the App.js then if I want to cancel it I do `source.cancel("Request canceled.");` ? I would have to create 2 source variables in this case then..?